# Unable to cast redshift column to integer due to empty values

Tags: casting, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table with a column which has empty values rarely. It is expected to have only integer values but some places empty values exist. When I try to cast it using :: it throws error -

```
[Code: 500310, SQL State: XX000]  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid digit, Value 'B', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid digit, Value 'B', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
  code:      1207
  context:   BEVEL_ON
  query:     34112149
  location:  :0
  process:   query1_836_34112149 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify you have a text column that contains numeric characters most of the time and you want to case this to integer, right?  It also sounds like you believe that the only only non-numeric values are the empty string ''.

If this is the case then the solution is fairly simple - change the empty string to NULL before casting.  The DECODE statement is my go to for this:

```
DECODE(col_X, '', NULL, col_X)::INT
```

If a more varied set of strings are in the column then using regexp_replace() to strip all the non-numeric characters would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
text_to_int_alt(
case 
when regexp_replace(convert(varchar, creative_id), '[^0-9]', '') <> '' then 
regexp_replace(convert(varchar, creative_id), '[^0-9]', '') 
end)
```